# Verfiying the solution to a simple problem real about an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f,p,d \ge 0$ such that

$$
f \ge G(d):=\begin{cases}p^2/2,&\mbox{ if }p \le d,\\ pd-d^2/2,&\mbox{ else.}\end{cases}
$$

In terms of $f$ and $p$, I'm interested in finding the largest possible value for of $d$.

> **Question.** *Could someone kindly verify my argument below.*

### Argument

It is clear that $G(d) \le p^2/2$ for any $d \ge 0$. Now,

- If $f \ge p^2/2$, then the inequality $f \ge G(d)$ has solution set all of $\mathbb R_+$.
- If $f < p^2/2$, then the inequality $f \ge G(d)$ is equivalent to $d < p$ and $f \ge pd - d^2/2$, i.e
  $$
  d \le p-\sqrt{p^2-2f} = \dfrac{2f}{p+\sqrt{p^2-2f}}.
  $$

---

**Context.** *The problem is quite elementary, but is a crucial part of a bigger argument (not presented here). A bug in the solution to this elementary problem could therefore have a big (negative) impact on the bigger argument.*

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks alot.